# INDEX with MATCH with FIND/SEARCH & position

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, formula

I have a fairly complex issue where I need to find matches of a short string within a long string, with the search being limited to the first few characters of the long string.

A long search turned up this array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$8:$A$9,MATCH(1,--NOT(NOT(FIND($A$8:$A$9,A1))),0)),"no match")}
```

With that I was able to get part of the way, but don't want to get matches if the value is not found within the first few characters, and I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

How can I adapt the above formula to limit the search to within the first few characters of the value, thus getting the formula to not match the values in cells A3 and A6, returning the desired result in Col-C? Or is there a different formula I should be using?

Here is a sample of the data (my data is quite complex, but the principle is the same):

```
    A (value)           B (result with current formula)     C (desired result)
1   1apple1234567890    apple                               apple
2   12apple123456789    apple                               apple
3   123456apple12345    apple                               no match
4   1peach1234567890    peach                               peach
5   12peach123456789    peach                               peach
6   123456peach12345    peach                               no match
7   
8   apple
9   peach
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxvGY.png)

EDIT:
After playing around to learn how the formula works, I was able to achieve the desired result using an IF criteria for the FIND array:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$8:$A$9,MATCH(1,--NOT(NOT(IF(FIND($A$8:$A$9,A2)>3,0,1))),0)),"no match")}
```

Comment: How many characters is "the first few characters"?

Comment: Hi BigBen - I'd like to search within the first 3 or 4 characters.

Comment: Which one is it? 3 or 4? Please choose.

Comment: I'll say 4, but wouldn't the desired limit be specified in the formula and be possible to change easily?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, just wanted to nail it down for the purposes of answering the question at hand.

Comment: Right, sorry! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array formula (use Ctrl+Shift+Enter) works perfectly:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$8:$A$9,MATCH(1,--NOT(NOT(IF(FIND($A$8:$A$9,A2)>3,0,1))),0)),"no match")}
```

Comment: Make sure you note that it requires Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of regular Enter, for future readers understanding.

Answer (score 1):

use Search and Left:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$9:$A$10)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$9:$A$10,LEFT(A2,4+LEN($A$9:$A$10))))),1)),"no match")
```

Replace the `4+` with the number of characters that would satisfy: `the first few characters of the value`

[image]